# selenium with python, how to handle two text field in alert box?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, alert

I am new in selenium with python and still in practice

selenium with python, may I how to handle two text field in alert box? I did search on Google and some pages mention to using javascriptexecutor but I don't know how's it work and xpath is not working? thank you

Blockquote

Info
website: https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth

Both username and password is admin

Here is my code below:

> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

> options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
> options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
> driver.maximize_window()
> driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")

> promptAlertUsername  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located())
> promptAlertUsername.sendKeys("admin")

> promptAlertPassword  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located())
> promptAlertPassword.sendKeys("admin")

> time.sleep(2)
> driver.quit()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

This is `Basic Http Authentication` modal. The easiest way to handle it - using simple link syntax `https://login:password@url`.

In your case you can login via

```py
url = "https://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"
driver.get(url)
```

or

```py
login = 'admin'
password = 'admin'
url = f"https://{login}:{password}@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"
driver.get(url)
```