# Java, Selenium: NoAlertPresent no such allert error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, alert

While trying to automate a flow which includes an 'alert' popup after the click of a button, I am sending an `driver.switchTo().alert();` command to focus the driver on the popup, but while trying to do so, I'm getting the `NoAlertPresent no such alert` error during compiling.

I've tried to do this in two ways, but for them both I'm having the same issue

Way 1:

```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    Alert promtAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String login = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    promtAlert.sendKeys(login + Keys.TAB + password);
    promtAlert.dismiss();
```

Way 2:

```
        try {
        sleep(1);
        Alert promtAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String login = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        promtAlert.sendKeys(login + Keys.TAB + password);
        promtAlert.dismiss();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        System.out.println("NoAlertPresent handled");
    }
```

But in both casses I'm not getting the expected result, that being passing the variables and "selecting" the dismiss option for the popup.

I am getting the error specifically for the line: `Alert promtAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();`

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong in this case?

Comment: is your alert - Basic HTTP Authentication, where you should enter login and password? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77075500/selenium-with-python-how-to-handle-two-text-field-in-alert-box/77076681#77076681 - Does this answers your question?

Comment: Hi @Yaroslavm, yes, I'm trying to do exactly that. I've checked the answer and tried to recreate it in java (using the first example) and it helped, thanks!